# Struts2 action embedded in URL

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am working on web application that uses Struts 2 framework. I need to bring some changes on the this web application so I am going through it. On the JSP page I found

```jsp
<form name="viewIntegrationFormId" id="viewIntegrationFormId" action="<integration:urlAction actionName='/integration/viewIntegration'></integration:urlAction>" method="POST">
```

What is confusing in this is the `action`. Usually it is straight forward like `action= someActionName`. This way we can map it to the actual POJO.

So what is the action name in the above and how can I map to the Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Struts2 action mapper is using action names without slashes. So from the path `/integration/viewIntegration` you can determine the namespace and action name:

- Namespace : `/integration`
- Action name: `viewIntegration`